# launching new activity from given example

Tags: android, android-activity, navigationbar

Hey i was looking at the navigation bar example here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

in that example the list is loaded through strings. and then the arrays are used as names to identify images from the 'drawable'. I would like to know how i can change the code to launch a new activity instead of showing an image.

Here is the part of the corresponding code from the site:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
        String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                        "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
        getActivity().setTitle(planet);
        return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(LauncherActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: 1.have your image 2.setup click listener 3.start activity.  so what do you really want

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fav);

image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TargetActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("customTag", someTag);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

you can replace `getActivity()` with `CurrentActivity.this` in most cases.

edit: am i getting closer?

Comment: sorry but no. if you take a look at the whole code, its using the string-array texts to identify images from the drawable folders. i would like to know how i can change it to show launch another activity when i click the item instead of fetching the image from drawable